# CMake & GraphViz -> Generate per target, but ignore single Libs there completely

Tags: cmake, graphviz

With the option "GRAPHVIZ_GENERATE_PER_TARGET" I can generate dot-files for all my libs. Fine.
With the option "GRAPHVIZ_IGNORE_TARGETS" I can ignore some of the targets (like e.g. a special logger lib). Also fine.

I didn't manage to not show the ignored targets in other targets dot-files. I want to completely get rid of the "GRAPHVIZ_IGNORE_TARGETS" targets in any dot-file.

The only option I see is parsing the file and remove the line that ends on the target's name (in comment) and the following line (creating the label). Plus I have to check to remove all the dependencies.

Is there another way I miss?

I played around with the GRAPHVIZ options but could not get a proper result...